# How can I add some view (eg. 10) that created with inflater?

Tags: android

How can I add some view or remove that created with inflater?
when I’m going to adding second of view it crached

```
  View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sector, linearLayout, false);
  int i=0;

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (myEditText.getText().toString().equals("") || i >= 10) {
                return;
            } else {
                linearLayout.addView(view);
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
    imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            myEditText.setText("");
            linearLayout.removeView(view);
            i--;
        }
    });
```

LOG : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Please explain more, and also show logcat as you say it crashed

Comment: the error explains itself

Comment: You have used `linearLayout.removeView(view);`. shouldn't it be `linearLayout.removeView(arg0);` as that's the argument in onClick?

Comment: @mihail can you write correct code for me ?

Comment: I don't know what is the idea of the whole project. Your error is that you create a view and you try to add it multiple times to another view/views. As the error says, `The specified child already has a parent.` You can check if your view already have a parent (`getParent`) and decide what you have to do then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the same inflated view every time. Try the following code instead:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (myEditText.getText().toString().equals("") || i >= 10) {
            return;
        } else {
            View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sector, linearLayout, false);
            linearLayout.addView(view);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple views by inflating them once the click listener registers a click:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (myEditText.getText().toString().equals("") || i >= 10) {
            return;
        } else {
            View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sector, linearLayout, false);
            linearLayout.addView(view);
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```

Then a click on imgDelete object would remove the last view inside the layout.

```
imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        myEditText.setText("");
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        // Get total view count
        int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
        // Remove last view inside the layout
        linearLayout.removeViewAt(childCount-1);
        i--;
    }
});
```

I believe that's the behaviour you are looking for.